# How to create a web editor for a new language?

Tags: web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, dsl, javacc

I have developed a new domain-specific language (DSL) using [Javacc](https://javacc.java.net/) parser generator. Now, I want to create a rich web editor for this language (using [Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/) and [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)), so that it can be easily used by everyone. I am looking to implement some cool features like auto-complete, code formatting, syntax highlighting etc. Can anyone guide me on the general approach or any standard algorithms for implementing these features ? Are you aware of any open-source implementations that I can glance through to get an overall idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/). Check [here](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) to see how to create an new module (for your DSL) for codemirror

Comment: Hey @green , Codemirror seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Does it also have features of a simple editor like creating new file, opening or saving files ? I was reading some online documentation and couldn't find any such information. For example, [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) web editors have this functionality. Is this feature also present in Codemirror ?